# Assigning array to JSON data in URL

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to assign a JSON array from a URL to a variable. Here's my code:

```
$.getJSON("tljson.json",function(result){
  var items = [];
  items.push(result);
});
```

However, 'alerting' the items only returns

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is alerting the result. You have an array of four objects, but alert only shows the default text representation of objects, `[object Object]`. Convert your data to string yourself before printing. For example, instead of `alert(result)`, you can try `alert(JSON.stringify(result))`.

Also, `alert` is ugly, annoying and hard to use; if you can, use `console.log()` and its friends instead, much easier on the programmer. Check the results in the JavaScript console. (This is under the assumption the `alert()` was for your own debugging benefit; if it's for users, try doing something in HTML instead.)

Comment: sorry, I was actually alerting the 'items' variable, and it still returns `[object Object]`

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi: Same answer applies.

Comment: @AnimeshTripathi: Just to point out: this is a display problem, your data is fine. You don't need to convert your data to a string if you're using it normally.

Answer (score 0):

It already is a variable, `result` is the json response that you can access the same way you would if you pushed it to items.